# RegEx for email with only one special character

Tags: regex

I am trying to modify a regex for emails (gmail) that should contains special characters like _%+-. but only one, not more

I made 2 test cases below that are both passing

I also tried [a-z0-9]+.+[a-z0-9] instead of [A-Z0-9_%+-.] but both test cases are passing

[image]

Comment: It is `/^[A-Z0-9]+(?:[_%+.-][A-Z0-9]+)?@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i` or `/^[A-Z0-9]+[_%+.-][A-Z0-9]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i` (if there must be at least three chars before `@` with `.` in the middle only).

Comment: please be aware that @gmail.com addresses can contain as many "." as you want, the are ignored. This means you *cannot* have two different mail addresses there that only differ in the number or position of "."
This is a "feature" of gmail.com that might or might not be relevant for other mail providers. I wrote it here because you mentioned gmail in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the right regex for my question

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+(?:[_%+.-][A-Z0-9]+)?@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can try with

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+(?:[_%+.-][A-Z0-9]+)?@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

or

```
/^[A-Z0-9]+[_%+.-][A-Z0-9]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

(if there must be at least three chars before @ with . in the middle only).
Try to give us more test cases to check your requirements, you can check [here](https://regex101.com/r/GhdtHT/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
^[^@_\%+\-\.]+[^@][^@_\%+\-\.]+@[A-Za-z\.]+$
```

Explanation:

- `^`: begin of string
- `[^@_\%+\-\.]+`: any character other than @ or special character (_%+-.)
- `[^@]`: any character other than @ *(here will match the special character, if present)*
- `[^@_\%+\-\.]+`: any character other than @ or special character (_%+-.)
- `@`: @
- `[A-Za-z\.]+`: any combination of alphabetical character and dot
- `$`: end of string

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/86Vxyh/1).

Note: the considered special characters are the one you listed in your problem statement. If there are further special characters, you just need to add them inside explained part 2 and 4.

Answer (score -1):

This should meet your need (some may be invalid in format):
`^[a-z0-9]*[_%+\-.][a-z0-9]*`...

If there must be characters surrounding those special chars (valid in format):
`^[a-z0-9]+[_%+\-.][a-z0-9]+`...

Comment: The `^[a-z0-9]*[_%+-.][a-z0-9]*` will also match a comma. `^[a-z0-9]*[_%+\-.][a-z0-9]*` [*will match*](https://regex101.com/r/OoqXXO/1) an email like `.@blah.com`

Comment: Sorry for the unescaped dash, it's now fixed.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, the OP doesn't tell if there have any length restrictions.